# Django i18n routing doesn't work properly

Tags: routes, django-i18n

I have a problem with Django i18n routing. I want to set language in URL but doesn't work. I created urls.py in project, and in app another urls.py. The code looks like this:

personal/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from personalasier import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'personal.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^cv/$',include('personalasier.urls')),
)
```

personalasier.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from personalasier import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

When I access to / or /cv returns 404 and shows me:

```
Using the URLconf defined in personal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
   ^admin/
   ^es/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

And if I access to /es/, /es/cv/ or /es/cv gives another 404 with this result:

```
Using the URLconf defined in personal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
     ^admin/
The current URL, es/, didn't match any of these.
```

Finally i tried to reverse URL and throws and exception:

```
>>>from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate
>>> activate("es")
>>> reverse("index")
Traceback (most recent call last):
    file "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 551, in reverse
        return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 468, in _reverse_with_prefix(lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to activate the language? Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns. Have you tried from the command line? Does it work?

Comment: I tried with shell, i activated language, execute revert and Python gave me exception...

Comment: Just tried with a clean Django installation and worked for me. Are you still having the issue? Are you using Django 1.7?